# Resistive sensor reading ADC

Tags: sensor, operational-amplifier, resistors, adc, gain

I have to make an ADC conversion with an ATXmega MCU, in an air quality application.

The input is a voltage divider between a voltage reference. The sensing resistor vary in relation to a gas concentration. I read the voltage between a load resistor and ground. Since the conversion is not high precision (12 bit) we don't want to wast any bit. The sensing resistor can reach the max value of 60 k: in this case the V on the Load Resistor will be at minimum.

The solution we found is to subtract this minimum voltage from the Vin with an op amp.

And now the questions: The voltage divider interact with the resistors of the diff op amp circuit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier)?

Will it be useful to place a unity gain buffer on between the Vref_min and the negative input pin of the op amp?

Is this idea is achievable with a normal low noise op amp like this?

http://it.farnell.com/texas-instruments/tl072ip/ic-op-amp-jfet-pdip8/dp/1459704 ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fijdZL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here the schematic. I have to put an unity gain buffer instead of "???" node?

Is the circuit ok?

Comment: Can you include a circuit diagram (edit your question, then hit Ctrl-M and draw one) and a link to the datasheet of the sensor?

Comment: By adding a unity gain (buffer) amplifier you will get over the problem of source resistance, especially if the resistance varies. The tl072 is a good general purpose op amp but you might consider something with a bit lower noise such as an LT1012 or similar.

Comment: With your resistor to ground, what is the minimum voltage you get (sensor @ 60kohm) and what is the maximum voltage you expect (sensor @ minimum resistance)?

Comment: @Andyaka it depends on Vref and Rload. With a Vref of 2.048V and a 10k Rload The voltage on Rl varies from 0.293V to 1.575. If i subtract 0.293V with a no-gain differentiator like in the schematic the range will be 0 - 1.282V, and I can use all the 12bit of the ADC conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a reference voltage of (say) 3V, the range your input will see is: -

- 3V * 10k/13k = **2.307V** (sensor at 3kohms)
- 3V * 10k/70k = **0.428V** (sensor at 60kohms)

If you used a 50uA current excitation and a grounded sensor, the range your input will see is: -

- 50e-6 * 3k = **0.15V** (sensor at 3kohms)
- 50e-6 * 60k = **3.0V** (sensor at 60kohms)

With a current excitation the percentage of your 3V reference range used is **95%**.
With voltage and resistor excitation you only get **63%** of the range.

If your reference voltage is lower or higher, the above "range" statements are still true.

[image]

Here is an example. An ADC input is directly connected to the sensor. The sensor is fed with 50uA via the PNP transistor. The 50uA is measured across "R" and compared with "V" by the op-amp. The op-amp keeps the current through R at a value that generates a voltage "V" across it. Values could be R=10k and V=0.5V or R=20k and V=1V. Op-amp should be chosen that has close-to-either-rail IO performance like an AD8605 (used many times by me in this same configuration for strain gauge excitation).

Here's a quick DC simulation for 60k and 3k loads: -

[image]

Transistor used is BC547C or BC847C for those with good eye-sight.

Note that due to small base currents in the transistor, the current isn't 50uA but 49.846uA with 60kohm load and 49.849uA when loaded at 3kohms. Note also the voltages across the sensor - 2.991V on 60k load and 149.5mV on 3k load.

Comment: The problem is that the internal reference of the ADC is 1V, so I need to concentrate the output of the op amp in the range [0-1V] or [0-2V] (the last with a 0.5 internal gain). I have no experience with current excitation..

Comment: @Mark - For current excitation think of a constant current source that produces a low level of current into the sensor resistor. As Andy indicated the other side of the sensor resistor is grounded. This scheme allows full use of the A/D input range because the excitation current can be set to that it produces the max A/D input when the sensor resistor is at its highest value. The current source wants to be biased from some voltage rail that is higher than the A/D input range so that the current source has enough compliance to deal with the changes in load on it.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I couldn't have put it better my self.

Comment: Sounds good. I ask you another step. In your scheme I put a 20K resistor R and a V of 1. When Rsense is at maximum val = 60k the overall resistance is 80k, so the current is 12.5mA. i dont see the role of the op amp in this circuit. There must be a voltage difference between the two R pin, so the PNO is always excited. Or not? Thanks guys!

Comment: @Mark you must have got this wired up incorrectly. The 1V needs to be referenced to the positive supply rail (5V). The currents drawn should be 50micro amps certainly not milli-amps. The op-amp is needed to stabilize the voltage across the resistor to exactly 1V an 1V divided by 20kohms is 50 micro amps. Are you simulating it?

Comment: You are right, I made a wrong calculation. It seems a great solution. In this case with a 50uA current and a 60k resistor I will obtain 3V at the input of the ADC. And with Rsensse = 3k Vin=0.15V. My goal is to obtain a Vin range as close as possible to [0-1V]. Any tips?

Comment: @Mark - use a smaller voltage (say 0.3333V) or increase the resistor to 60k - with 1V across it, it'll generate 16.667uA through the 60k giving you 1V!!! If you do have the gain of 0.5 facility I'd consider using that and run at 33.333uA (30k emitter resistor). See also the simulation I attached to the end of my answer (50uA)

Comment: You are my saver (I don't know if it's a correct way of saying). As you can see my english is very poor. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry last question: How can I obtain the 1V and 5V values? With voltage reference? With a Zener? Finally, is possible to shift the Vin range between [0-1]V and not between [0.15-1]V?

Comment: Your ADC on the ATMega should be able to produce 5V. If it is 3V3 let me know. For the 1V you ought to use a decent "shunt reference" like REF1112 - it is 1.25V but that is not a worry because you get the current back to what you need by making the emitter resistor 25% bigger. The positive end (called Vo) of the REF1112 connects to 5V and the negative end you can feed via a 1Kohm resistor to ground. The junction of 1k resistor and neg end of REF1110 feeds the op-amp

Comment: Regarding shifting the voltage I'd be inclined not to. You will find that if you average several readings inside the atmega you'll get plenty of resolution - it's called "dithering" and can increase resolution by a couple of bits. There are internet articles on it.

Comment: @Andyaka - He's not using an ATmega, it's using an AT**x**mega. The internal vRef of those is indeed 1.0V, and the maximum vRef the parts support is actually Vcc-0.6V, which is 2.7V (Vcc Max is 3.3V - they don't support 5V operation).

Comment: @ConnorWolf - I think the op should figure this out - I gave a hint a couple of comments up that if it were 3V3 he should let me know but the basic principal remains the same - the Ilimit circuit will work from 3V3 and he can drive it with 16.7uA.

Comment: The micro is an ATXMega256A3BU and the Vcc is 3.3V. I didn't add any comment because the operating principle is the same. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, I don't want to move this conversation on the chat because I think it will be useful for other users. @Andyaka another thing, My colleague said me that the 3.3V Vcc is not very precise. This disturbs the precision current circuit? I think yes. Solutions?

Comment: @Mark No, it does not rely on the 3V3 accuracy at all. So if it were 3.1 or 3.5V it wouldn't matter. The REF1112 defines an accurate 1.25V and the op-amp, in closed-loop forces that 1.25V across the emitter resistor. However, a noisy supply can cause problems so decouple the REF1112 with a 100nF cap. However, even if it becomes noisy, the average current will remain steady and as I mentioned earlier you can filter the noise in code. You can also add 100nF or 1uF+ across the sensor too.

Comment: @Andyaka can you explain me the role of the transistor? Is not possible to obtain the same effect with a voltage reference and a resistor? Thanks!

Comment: The transistor collector is the real current source and its collector current is determined by the voltage across its emitter resistor. This emitter voltage, due to the op-amp feedback resistor is held at exactly 1V below 5V positive rail and this means the current into the emitter is constant. Your idea about a voltage ref and resistor I don't understand - a new question would help. It doesn't hurt to offer up something that may work.

Comment: But the transistor doesn't amplify the current?

Comment: @Mark I don't understand your question. Of course the transistor amplifies current because that is what BJTs do - gain of a BJT is Ic/Ib

Comment: @Andyaka I thank you for your patience. And the other question is: isn't better to link the negative feedback on Ic and not on Ie, considering the Voltage drop of the BJT?

Comment: No that won't work - the negative feedback is "measuring" the voltage across the emitter resistor. The op-amp works to keep the voltage across the emitter resistor at 1V. It does this by using the transistor and it happens to be that the emitter current is virtually same as collector current.

Comment: @Andyaka Ok now i'm now convinced. On monday I will realize my circuit on a stripboard. The last doubt is the noise. A so small current can be disturbed by ambient noise and also by the stripboard circuit itself.

Comment: If you do see some noise that affects results then firstly make sure that whatever you use to generate the 1V between Vin+ and positive power rail (5v?) has a decent capacitor across it like 100nF. The only other noise source worth mentioning is the op-amp - if you can allow a capacitor from collector to ground you'll make noise really low.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly address your question, it does describe a problem you are going to run into in the near future.

Basically, the ATxmega ADCs are [pretty much](http://blog.frankvh.com/2010/01/03/atmel-xmega-adc-problems-solutions/) [unusable](http://blog.frankvh.com/2010/09/09/followup-to-atmel-xmega-adc-problems/) when connected to the xmega's internal 1.0V reference. You get ~16 counts of noise no matter what you do.

The general consensus seems to be that if you want to use the ADxmega internal ADC, you really *have* to use an external reference. Ideally, you could use the entire 0-3.3V range, but the ADC only supports references up to Vcc - 0.6V, so 2.5V is probably the best idea.

I recently was working on a project that had some user-interface pots that were connected to the xmega ADCs. I indeed wound up having noise issues. I was able to solve them by **massively** oversampling (x4096 times!), but it still only gave me maybe 10 bits of usable resolution.
Now, my layout was really, **really** non-ideal (the UI stuff was added after I had sent the boards off to be fabbed, it was hung off what was *supposed* to be just a debugging port, and had wires everywhere and whatnot).

Atmel has *supposedly* "fixed" the ADC issues on parts with the "u" suffix (Such as ATxmega32A4U vs ATxmega32A4), but I have not had a change to work with the "U" parts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read on avrfreaks about this issues with the internal 1V refence. My idea is to test it, and find out if the ATXMega256A3BU has a fixed ADC internal reference. I think thaht if the conditioning circuit and the driver are well designed it will be possible to insert in a second time an external reference, changing resistors and a few lines of code. Do you agree with this plan?
Have you experienced ADC voltage reading on a resistor? You used current excitation or voltage divider?

Comment: @Mark - I was just taking ADC readings of a straight-up voltage divider, single-ended mode, with no external reference (I didn't have the pins!), so I can't really comment on the viability of other options first-hand.

Comment: If I were in your situation, I would add the PCB footprints for adding an inexpensive 2.5V reference on the PCB, and have some optional 0Ω resistor footprints so you can install it and connect it up if your plan for signal conditioning doesn't pan out. It's worth noting that the filtering on the analog input *probably* won't help much, as the noise is *internal to the ADC*. Your options are really just: 1. Use an external vRef, 2. Use the internal voltage divider off Vcc, and 3. Use the internal vRef, and decimate the hell out of it.

Comment: There are some really, really cheap voltage references out there. The LM336Z25 is $0.51 in single quantities on digikey. That, a resistor, and a cap would be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can buffer the inputs to the differential amp, and there may be reasons to do so.  However, an *Instrumentation Amplifier* like the [AD620](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD620.pdf) is already pre-buffered and has easily adjustable gains. If You need single-sided rail-to-rail functionality (one power supply), there's the AD623.

Comment: The low cost is an important feature for this project. Obviously without killing performance. I proposed the TL072IP beacuse it has two channels and it's possible to use one channel for buffering the negative input and the other channel for the differential operation. And it cost 0,68€ vs the 5.14€ of the AD623.